# Behat Script unable to detect CKEditor toolbar element

Tags: php, drupal, ckeditor, behat

I am trying to automate a drupal website by clicking on one of the ckeditor toolbar icon **(image below)**

CKEditor:

[image: CKEditor image]

I have tried to detect the element using the following below xpath

**`//span[@class='cke_button_icon cke_button__media_browser_icon']`**

but still it is not able to find the element

Xpath for the element in chrome console:

[image: Xpath for the element in chrome console image]

So , I am thinking that script is not able to detect the element due to some javascript issue.

Can anyone please suggest me any solution to detect the following toolbar icon in the image attached using behat script and perform a click operation on it.

Comment: Maybe the element is in a iframe and you need to switch to the iframe first.

Comment: I tried to do that but still it was not able to identify it

Answer (score 0):

One can click any CKEditor toolbar element using the following javascript code if the behat script is unable to detect using xpath/id/class etc. :

```
$javascriptClickEvent = "document.getElementById('id_of_the_element').click()";
$this->getSession()->evaluateScript($javascriptClickEvent);
```